# HTTP AKKA Getting "Request is missing required query parameter" when trying to parse request

Tags: scala, akka-http

URL being tested:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/e/start?p=test
```

The code for parsing the request:

```scala
pathPrefix(version) {
  path("e" / Segment) { eventType =>
    parameter("p".as[String]) { p =>
      ..
      ..
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `version`?

Comment: What versions of the akka libraries are you using?

Comment: Pretty old one. It used to be Spray back then. Version: 1.3.4

Comment: I can confirm, that this code works as expected in the [Doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html) with the latest akka-http version 10.4.0, so you may consider [migrating from Spray to akka-http](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/migration-guide/migration-from-spray.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda harder than expected at the current state of the project..